# Find all integers $a,b,c$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

This question comes from the 2007 IMO shortlist:

> Find all integers $a,b,c$ such that $ab-c$, $bc-a$ and $ca-b$ are powers of two (of the form $2^k$ where $k \geq0$).

What are some methods of finding solutions?

Comment: I impulsively upvoted because the problem is cool, but can you please show us any ideas/working you've come up with/done? Have you looked at similar problems (here on MSE) you can link to that might guide other users in providing an answer? Also, add the tag contest-math if you edit it.Thanks

Comment: @Shakespeare I don't know where to start to be honest, and yes I have looked for other problems on MSE related to this that might help.

Comment: It is not formally a duplicate, there is no restriction here on positivity of $a,b,c$. For example, a permutations of $(0,-1,-1)$ are also solutions.